# SpriteKit and SKPhysicsWorld runs faster on device when not through Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I am developing a game with Swift, SpriteKit and SpriteKit's PhysicsWorld and PhysicsBody solutions.

When I run the game on my phone (connected to my computer ) through Xcode the physics runs substantially faster (although SKAction animations are the same speed) compared to when I run the same compiled version but on my phone, not through Xcode (connected to computer or not).

What could cause this? What behaviors should I expect my users to get?

Update: I have attempted using release build but it makes no difference. I have also noticed Ads are not displayed, buttons opening GC and my website don't work.

Comment: Unfortunately your problem is too vague for SO,  anything could be causing this problem, it is not normal behavior